# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I want to connect with my server using websocket but I cant deal with this error.

[image]

I have checked all the recommended solutions but none of them work. I am using Angular 15.

```
 private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/socket'
  private stompClient: any;

  constructor(private app: AppService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
  }

  initializeWebSocketConnection(){
    let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    let that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function() {
        that.stompClient.subscribe("/test", (message :any) => {
          if(message.body){
            console.log(message.body);
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: what is this Stomp here, have we injected it in constructor

Answer (score -1):

By defining global variable either on `polyfills.ts` or `index.html` should resolve the issue.

**polyfills.ts**

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <script>
    var global = window;
  </script>
</head>
```